# modifying multiple tables in one query with aprepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following prepared query I am using with mysql and php. It is to allow users to be added to a particular category, passed in via $subcat.

```
$alterQuery = "UPDATE AUCTIONS SET subcat= ? WHERE article_no= ?";
   if ($altRecord = $con->prepare($alterQuery)) {
       $altRecord->bind_param("ss", $subcat, $pk);
       $altRecord->execute();
    $altRecord->close();
    echo "true";
    }
```

What I would like to do, in the same query, is insert a new record in the USERS table only inserting the username, after checking that the username does not already exist. Is it possible just to change $alterQuery to:

What is the best what to do this?

Check for the username, and if it == null, do a subsequent insert? can I have two different queries executed in the same if block?

edit: attaching database scheme in response to comment

```
AUCTIONS    

    ARTICLE_NO      varchar(20) primary key
    ARTICLE_NAME    varchar(100)
    SUBTITLE    varchar(20)
    CURRENT_BID     decimal(5,2)
    START_PRICE     decimal(5,2)
    BID_COUNT   varchar(20)
    QUANT_TOTAL     varchar(20)
    QUANT_SOLD  varchar(20)
    ACCESSSTARTS    varchar(30)
    ACCESSENDS  varchar(20)
    ACCESSORIGIN_END    varchar(20)
    USERNAME    varchar(20)     
    BEST_BIDDER_ID  varchar(20)     
    FINISHED    tinyint(4)  
    WATCH   tinyint(4)      
    BUYITNOW_PRICE  decimal(5,2)    
    PIC_URL     varchar(120)    
    PRIVATE_AUCTION     tinyint(4)
    AUCTION_TYPE    varchar(20)     
    ACCESSINSERT_DATE   varchar(20)
    ACCESSUPDATE_DATE   varchar(20)
    CAT_DESC    varchar(20)     
    CAT_PATH    varchar(20)     
    ARTICLE_DESC    text    
    COUNTRYCODE     varchar(20)
    LOCATION    varchar(20)
    CONDITIONS  varchar(20)
    REVISED     tinyint(4) 
    PAYPAL_ACCEPT   tinyint(4) 
    PRE_TERMINATED  tinyint(4) 
    SHIPPING_TO     varchar(20)
    FEE_INSERTION   decimal(5,2)
    FEE_FINAL   decimal(5,2)
    FEE_LISTING     decimal(5,2)
    PIC_XXL     tinyint(4) 
    PIC_DIASHOW     tinyint(4) 
    PIC_COUNT   varchar(20)
    ITEM_SITE_ID    varchar(20)
    STARTS  datetime    
    ENDS    datetime    
    ORIGIN_END  datetime
    SUBCAT  varchar(20)

USERS
    username    varchar(30) primary key
    firstname   varchar(30)
    lastname    varchar(30)
    flaggedauctions     varchar(30)
    lastauction     varchar(30)     
    street1     varchar(30)     
    city1   varchar(30)     
    postcode1   varchar(30)
    street2     varchar(30)
    city2   varchar(30)     
    postcode2   varchar(30)
    phone   varchar(30)     
    mobilephone     varchar(30) 
    fax     varchar(30)     
    email   varchar(30)     
    website     varchar(30) 
    bank    varchar(30)     
    banknumber  varchar(30)
    accountnumber   varchar(30)
    comments    varchar(30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be best to create a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_add_user_to_category(_subcat VARCHAR(20), _article_no VARCHAR(20), _username VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
        UPDATE  AUCTIONS
        SET     subcat= _subcat
        WHERE   article_no= _article_no;
        INSERT
        INTO    users (username)
        VALUES  (_username)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY
        UPDATE
        username = username;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and call it from your code:

```
$alterQuery = "CALL prc_add_user_to_category(?, ?, ?)";
   if ($altRecord = $con->prepare($alterQuery)) {
       $altRecord->bind_param("ss", $subcat, $pk, $userid);
       $altRecord->execute();
    $altRecord->close();
    echo "true";
    }
```

Checked and proved to compile and work against your schema on `5.2.0-falcon-alpha-community-nt-log`

Comment: This failed compeltely with mysql 5.0. I tried the following: CREATE PROCEDURE addToCategory(_subcat INT, _article_no INT, _username INT)
BEGIN
        DECLARE 
        UPDATE  AUCTIONS
        SET     subcat= _subcat
        WHERE   article_no= _article_no;
        INSERT
        INTO    users (username)
        VALUES  (_username)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        SET     username = username;
END

It said to check my syntax near UPDATE AUCTIONS

Comment: It now gives:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
BEGIN
        UPDATE  AUCTIONS
        SET     subcat= _subcat
        WHE' at line 1

Comment: Add length to a VARCHAR definition

Comment: you mean for my fields? They all have a length

Comment: Yep. I am using that, and it gives an error and states to check the syntax near 'UPDATE  AUCTIONS

Comment: Sorry then, I can't help you without seeing your schema.

Comment: I will amend it to my question.

Comment: In the future, please post your schema as CREATE TABLE statements so that it can be easily pasted into the query tool.

Comment: I am sorry about the scehem, I will post it as a create table staement from now on. I still get a syntax error, this time near DELIMITER $$. I am putting it into the sql tool through phpmyadmin

Comment: You use DELIMITER $$ when using MySQL command line tool. For phpmyadmin, just paste text from CREATE PROCEDURE to END

Comment: It still gives a error near 'UPDATE  AUCTIONS, when using from create to end. I am using Mysql 5.0.32 on Linux.

Comment: Hmm, I am trying with DELIMITER ;; 
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_add_to_category(_subcat VARCHAR(20), _article_no VARCHAR(20), _username VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
        UPDATE  AUCTIONS
        SET     SUBCAT= _subcat
        WHERE   ARTICLE_NO= _article_no;
        INSERT
        INTO    USERS (username)
        VALUES  (_username)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY
        UPDATE
        username = USERNAME;
END;;
and it gives an error near DELIMITER..

Comment: Is there any way to do this other than as a stored procedure?

Comment: No, if you want to have it done in one round-trip to the server, you'll have to create a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that? Enclosing your queries in a transaction will either be a complete commit or rollback.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity

Comment: How is the operation I want to perform not atomic. It is always added to a category, and the username either is or is not inserted.

Comment: Up 1, because transactions are the way to go. Of course you can conditionally insert, but within the transaction. That way, if an error occurs, the whole thing will be rolled back, and in the good case you will get what you want. Nice and clean.

Comment: I thought my queries would be a transaction?

Comment: You need to enclose your queries with a begin/commmit. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-transaction-model.html